# Is it possible for CSS3 transitions or high memory objects to affect scrolling smoothness in Chrome?

Tags: performance, dom, memory-management, google-chrome, css

I'm working on a site with lots of CSS3 transitions (which are hardware accelerated) and high memory objects (for example, an array of 39 objects, each containing the full html source for a typical online news article) and I'm noticing some very choppy/jittery scrolling, which I've been unable to debug.

I've kept these high memory objects out of the DOM, which should prevent them from affecting DOM performance, however, I can't help but think that they are still having a negative effect.  I don't have code samples to post because I'm unsure of whether this is even an issue.

Please go to this site ([Orange](http://harrisnovick.com/orange)) and click on an article tile.  In the reader div that pops up over the page, try scrolling as you normally would.  Does it feel choppy/jittery?  Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: This site is totally non-functional for me in chrome (build 15.0.874.106) edit: it seems it loads *sometimes*... You might want to look into that. It may be your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 transitions, opacity, text and box-shadows and the like are certainly known to impact rendering speeds. In fact, even sites with heavy use of text-shadow alone can cause choppy scrolling on the average computer. Combining this with heavy use of javascript seems like a recipe for choppy web browsing.

edit: The loading animation on the o in orange is pretty awesome!

Comment: Thanks for your help Steve.  In the comment you left, you say "it may be your server."  I've been thinking this could be a problem as well, however, I have no idea how the server would affect DOM performance.  Can you illuminate?  Thanks. 

edit: A little background on the Server-Side end of things.  I'm using a basic LAMP stack, heavily GZIPing and caching all content.

Comment: @hnovick I can't be too sure about the server. It might have been a temporary hiccup, really. I was able to load part of the page, then it would hang pretty badly. About 3 minutes later, a refresh was successful and I managed to load the page. The thing that got me about the partial load the first time around was that it reaaallly bogged down chrome. It's really difficult to say why without replicating the issue though...

Comment: — I've done a lot of refactoring/optimization.  Can you clear cache, check it out again and let me know if performance seems any better?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's jittery. A page with a lot of Javascript will do that and frameworks like jQuery won't help at all. I'd recommend recoding as much as you can without using jQuery and passing it through JSLint (http://www.jslint.com/).

Try using Chrome's developer tools too to get an idea of what the bottleneck is.

Try disabling Javascript too and seeing if it's any better. If it isn't, then you know where your problem lies.

Comment: Oh.. right. It doesn't work at all without Javascript. You should probably make it so that does.

Comment: Normally I would use <noscript> tags and other accessibility methods to allow the page to function without JavaScript, however, being that this site is targeted towards readers of Hacker News, I'm starting out by targeting the technologies they are likely using, namely, WebKit and JavaScript.

Comment: Sure but I noticed that nothing shows up without JS, indicating that you're creating a lot of stuff on the fly which seems a little pointless to me.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. When the page loads, all internal markup/assets are rendered. The first thing that happens is JSON is pulled in from HNSearch, then I fetch the articles on the server and render the results via JSON. I don't really know of anyway of doing AJAX requests without JavaScript. I could render the first set of articles server-side but you would still need JavaScript to access any subsequent query results.